# global error variable remains nil after initialization

Tags: go

When I initialize an error variable globally it seems that it's nil to another function in the same package.
I don't understand why is this code not panicing?

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
)

var loadErr error

func main() {
    f, loadErr := os.Open("asdasd")
    if loadErr != nil {
        checkErr()
    }
    if f != nil {
        fmt.Println(f.Name())
    }
}

// panic won't be called because loadErr is nil
func checkErr() {
    if loadErr != nil {
        panic(loadErr)
    }
}
```

But when I do this, it seems to work as expected?

```
package main

import (
    "os"
)

var loadErr error

func main() {
    _, err := os.Open("asdasd")
    loadErr = err
    if loadErr != nil {
        checkErr()
    }
}

// panic will be called as expected
func checkErr() {
    if loadErr != nil {
        panic(loadErr)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
func main() {
    _, loadErr := os.Open("asdasd")
```

You create a **new, local** variable `loadErr`, the global one is never set. Use just `=`, not `:=`, to use the global one.

Edit: To hold the second value too, you have to predeclare the second variable:

```
var f *os.File
f, loadErr = os.Open("asdasd")
```

Unfortunately, you can't use `:=` here, as `:=` will not consider non-local variables and just create a local variable in this case.

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear. I eventually must use := because in real life situation I need to hold f as well

Comment: @J.Gorey so what is your question? You're creating a local variable that shadows the global one.

Answer (score 6):

The [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) creates new variables if the variables on the left side have been declared in an outer [scope](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope). **This is also true if not all variables are new on the left side**, which otherwise would be *redeclaration* (which does not introduce a new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original).

So if you want to assign value to the global variable, don't use short variable declaration but simple [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments). Of course, for a tuple assignment where one variable has been declared earlier, you must declare the other one too prior:

```
var f *os.File
f, loadErr = os.Open("asdasd")
if loadErr != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```

You can write it more compact:

```
var f *os.File
if f, loadErr = os.Open("asdasd"); loadErr != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```

There is also another option using short variable declaration, but then you must "manually" assign the error value to the global `loadErr` variable:

```
f, err := os.Open("asdasd")
loadErr = err
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```

Or more compact:

```
f, err := os.Open("asdasd")
if loadErr = err; err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```

See related / possible duplicate question: [How to use global var across files in a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34195360/golang-how-to-use-global-var-across-files-in-a-package/34195389#34195389)